# TYPO3 CSS file - css append every time different file

Tags: html, css, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I took over a TYPO3 site...

I would like to edit css file, in the inspector it shows me that the file is located: /typo3temp/vhs-assets-portal-css.css?1481533219

The problem is that .css?1481533219 is every time different (dynamicaly generated).

I edit already vhs-assets-portal-css but it doesnt apply changes live...

I would appreciate if somebody can help me, and tell me how this is generated and how to change this css file.

Thanks in advance!
Denis

Comment: Clear cache and view the css code in browser is there your changes done.

Comment: this is a temporary file, you should find the original, check this page for the location https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SkinningReference/CssFilesOrganization/Index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number after the question mark looks like a timestamp which might be used to do a fresh fetching from the server. This could be done to avoid a caching in the browser. This can be helpful if the file is generated on the fly and could contain changed content for every access. Especially if you a logged in in the BE.
For FE you should avoid such constructs as they increase traffic.

The name of the file lead to the assumption there is a call of the assets-style-viewhelper of ext:vhs. Have a look in your templates to identify the call and check whether it needs avoiding cache or whether the CSS-include might be better configured in TS.